# Meteor Synchronous call from Client to Server Method Call

Tags: meteor

Working on a meteor project and totally blocked on the below issue

- Customers Adds item to cart
- On clicking the “Place Order” capturing the ‘click’ event
- Calling a method on server sample code below Meteor.call()
- Now on the server side the method invokes some external API
- So I want to wait for the response back in the client examine the result and route to the confirmation page or display error message.
- With the call back, the control the transferred to default/current page and redirecting the the confirmation page and I have no way to examine the transaction is success of not

```js
Meteor.call('placeOder', order info, sequence, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        if(result) {
            console.log("Could not insert the order for the session  = "
                        + sessid + "Order = " + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        } else {
            console.log("Could not insert the order for the session  = " + sessid );
        }
    } else {        
        Session.set('orderStatus', 'Success');
        Router.go('confirmation',  {UniqueId: result.id});            
    }   
});
```

Any help to resolve would be greatly appreciated. Basically on client side I want to wait for response back from server, examine the response and route accordingly.

Jay

Comment: So why does not your code work? In general it should work as you describe. Btw, I don't understand last point in your wish list, could you elaborate?

Comment: The second parameter in the meteor.call - 'order info' - looks very odd, why has it got a space in it?